# SQL, join, subquery, derived table

Tags: sql, join

I have following table :

```
lead_id | status | list_id | user_id |
    1   |   ZP   |    1    |  2001   |
    2   |   ZP   |    2    |  2001   |
    3   |   ZP   |    2    |  2002   |
    4   |   ZP   |    1    |  2002   |
    5   |   ZP   |    1    |  2002   |
```

which is something like master table

now there is table like :

```
list_id | camp_id |
  1     | camp1   |
  2     | camp2   |
```

And i would like the following result :

```
user_id | camp1 | camp2 |
 2001   |   1   |   1   |
 2002   |   2   |   1   |
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation.

```
select m.user_id
,sum(case when m.list_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as camp1
,sum(case when m.list_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as camp2
from mastertable m
join othertable o on o.list_id = m.list_id
group by m.user_id
```